# Android Studio "cannot resolve symbol HttpRequest" when import HttpRequest.HttpRequest

Tags: java, android, ide

I have created a new Java class and wanted to import it in `MainActivity`. I tried:

```
import HttpRequest.HttpRequest
```

And I got:

> cannot resolve symbol HttpRequest

What am I doing wrong?

**Project structure:**

[image: Project structure]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DJimm.png please add picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpRequest.HttpRequest` **doesn't exist**.
You are importing the wrong class.

It should be:

```
import com.example.megido.myapplication.HttpRequest;
```

Also check this [link for more info](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html) about Android Studio Tips and Tricks.

> For quick fixes to coding errors, the IntelliJ powered IDE implements the **Alt + Enter** key binding to fix errors (missing imports, variable assignments, missing references, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want import another Class in Present class then you have to give its full path ie. import com.example.megido.myapplication.HttpRequest
If you trying to import HttpRequest for network request then you have to add the corresponding library to you project.
I hope it helps..